# Save user specified settings on flash drive

Tags: qgis

With some help in this forum I already managed to successfully setup Quantum GIS 1.8 on a flash drive (see my post on [Running QGis from flash drive](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/28771/running-qgis-from-flash-drive)).

QGis starts and runs stable on different computers, but I still have problems to port also user speficied settings. To port the settings I use the `[--configpath]` option as suggested in the QGis-Manual. According to this I changed the qgis.bat batch file this way to start QGis with a qgs-project file:

```
start "Quantum GIS" /B %OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis\bin\qgis.exe --configpath %DRV_LTR%\qgisconfig\ %DRV_LTR%\Daten\TESTPROJEKT.qgs
```

In general this works fine -  QGis starts with the determined project file on different working stations. And installed Plugins, for example, also appear installed when the flash drive is connected to another working station. But it seems, that the `[--configpath]` option does not port user speficied settings themselves: Installed Plugins do not appear checked when set to another workstation, removed toolbars on one machine appear on the other, so do by „Customization“ hidden parts of QGis.

It seems, that these UI-settings still are saved locally. When removing all entries in the Windows registry, keys appear from new in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\QuantumGIS` after running QGis.
I was hoping that the `[--configpath]` option could also save user specified settings on the flash drive. The overall goal of my work is to supply non-GIS experienced project partners with an easy to handle GIS-Data-Viewer, that can be used without installation. Especially with the new „Customization“ dialog QGis 1.8 seems to be perfect fort that, if not used Menus and Toolbars could just be turned off or hidden.

I am thankfull for any suggestions!

Comment: There seems to be a bug at the moment with QGIS ignoring the --config option for the customization stuff.

Comment: If this is a bug - how could this reported to the developer team of Quantum GIS?

Comment: You can report the bug here http://hub.qgis.org/projects/quantum-gis/issues

Comment: I reported the possible bug under the given adress. Thanks for the advice!

Comment: @mweiss I think it's best to post your answer to this question and accept it. That way people will know this question has been resolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reporting the bug to the QGIS developers the problem of ignoring the path of user speficied settings already has been fixed. When using nightly build of QGIS 1.9 through the OSGEO installer the changes are already made - and it seems to work stable!