# Saving project from QGIS to CD so it can be used on other computers?

Tags: qgis

For purpose of a project, I created a project in QGIS - aerophoto base and 3 layers. It works perfect on my computer, but if I save it on CD, the project doesent work on any other computer... I saved all data for layers & project works from CD, but only on computer, where it was created.

How can I save it, so it will be working on other comps, since I have to distribute this project to other partners?

I am using windows and QGIS 1.8.0. Lisboa

EDIT & MORE INFO:
my project is aerophoto based with one raster and 2 vector layers.
It works on my comp (where QGIS 1.8.0 Lisboa is installed).

Now I need to put it on USB (and few on CD), so I can take to my menthor and cooperants to see it... 
I copied all data (those are in same folder), I downloaded the QGIS Lisboa (.exe file) so everyone can install it. Now all is on usb.
It works on my computer, where this was created.
But when I try to see it on laptop (after installing QGIS), it serves me with error (runtime error) - same on my friend computer.

Proposal to make a USB option of qgis is nice, I am in a process of trying, but i suspect there is something else, because error is reported.

if possible, step by step solution, because I am comp analphabet actually :(

Comment: I have put all data and qGIS installation file (.exe) on a CD. that one works on a main computer. If I go to my laptop and install QGIS, program opens and reports an error. Did I miss something? Paths have been modified and path option set to relative.

Comment: it says: Runtime error. Visual C++ error

Comment: Do the other computers have QGIS installed and, if not, do you admin privileges to install it?

Comment: i dont mind to run or to install - as long as it works!

Answer (score 3):

There is an experimental plugin called QConsolidate in the repository, which saves all files related to a project in a single folder to make exchanges easier. But I don't know if it runs on your very old QGIS version.

http://giswiki.hsr.ch/QGIS_All-in-one_Project_Plugin has a similar approach.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that your data are not in a centralised database accessible to all the computers.  If this is the case and you are distributing your data as well, I would set up the project so that *everything* is in one main project folder (which may contain subfolders to organize the various data sources) including the QGIS project file.  Then check that relative paths has been set for the data.  Go to `Settings->Project Properties->General` and look for the `Save Paths` option (set it to 'Relative').

You should now be able to copy the entire self-contained project folder to the CD and copy it on to other computers.  If they have QGIS installed, everything should work.  For best results, I would copy the project folder off the CD and onto each hard-drive.

You can use the relative paths option without putting all the project data in one folder but you then need to ensure that all the other computers have identical folder structures for all the data... so it is probably easier in the long-run just to make it all self-contained.

**EDIT**
It also sounds like you need a portable version of QGIS.  If you need to distribute QGIS itself as well as the project then you will need to enable QGIS to run from a usb or similar medium.  This is the second half to your problem, which we can now see from your additional comments.  Have a look [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/28771/running-qgis-from-flash-drive) and [here](http://ceg-sense.ncl.ac.uk/geoanorak/code/qgis18usb.html) for solutions.

Comment: Please see my edit above

Comment: i managed to pull down QGIS 1.8 on a stick, but is not working on my usb - it serves me with: "The system cannot find the path specified"

Answer (score 0):

Go to the 'General tab' of the project properties and check if relative paths are selected. In 2.2: **project> Project properties> General tab**, in the save paths drop down menu. 
This was meant to be default from QGIS 1.73, but worth a look

Otherwise, does it work if you copy it from the CD to another computer? What version of QGIS are the others using?

Comment: thank you / others are me - I am having 1.8.0., because I will distribute program as well. Paths are set to relative

Comment: The portable version should do the job.

Comment: i surely hope so!